# "NV_ENC_ERR_INVALID_VERSION" error while using nvenc encoder

Tags: encode, nvidia

I am using the cuda nvenc encoder to encode an YUV frame. I want to stream the encoded h264 data using RTSP streaming. I need the SPSPPS buffer to do RTSP stream. I am using "nvEncGetSequenceParams" to get the spspps buffer. I have called this function after calling the "nvEncInitializeEncoder" function as expected.  I am getting the "NV_ENC_ERR_INVALID_VERSION" error which means I am passing wrong struct to this function. but I have checked multiple times the struct I have passed is correct. I think this can be driver version problem. I have Quadro k5000 GPU. I have tried this on driver version 331.82 and 337.88. Following is the code I am using.

```
NVENCSTATUS CNvEncoderH264::GetSPSPPSBUffer(char *SPSPPSBuffer)
{

    NVENCSTATUS nvSta = NV_ENC_SUCCESS;
    uint32_t size = 0;

    //m_spspps is of type NV_ENC_SEQUENCE_PARAM_PAYLOAD
    m_spspps.inBufferSize = 512;
    m_spspps.outSPSPPSPayloadSize = &size;
    SET_VER(m_spspps, NV_ENC_INITIALIZE_PARAMS);

    m_spspps.spsppsBuffer = SPSPPSBuffer;

    nvSta = m_pEncodeAPI->nvEncGetSequenceParams(m_hEncoder,&m_spspps);
    return nvSta;
}
```

Comment: NVENC is not NVCUVENC, and NVENC has nothing to do with CUDA.  These questions should not be tagged with CUDA.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I totally agree to the comment regarding the particular question, however the statement "NVENC has nothing to do with CUDA" is not entirely true - you can intialize NVENC with a CUDA floating context handle (which means involving some CUDA APIs in the NVENC code), color conversions on Direct 3D surfaces used as input for NVENC can be done with CUDA.

Comment: The GPU hw resources used for NVENC are completely separate from those used for CUDA, and the APIs are orthogonal.  Yes, they can interoperate, but there is no CUDA API that by definition manipulates NVENC functionality, and there is no NVENC API that by definition manipulates CUDA functionality.    Anyway the point of my comment is that NVENC questions should not be automatically tagged with CUDA, which is what appeared to be the case here.  NVENC is not part of CUDA.  Thanks for providing answers to this users questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the wrong version macro to the SPS/PPS structure. I don't have my NVIDIA code by hand, so I'll try to Google the right macro but rule of the thumb is that each structure has a specific version macro (ans you are using NV_ENC_INITIALIZE_PARAMS for the SPS/PPS structure which is definitely not right. I assume the type of `m_spspps` is `NV_ENC_SEQUENCE_PARAM_PAYLOAD`. So you should initialize it like this:

```
 m_spspps.version = NV_ENC_SEQUENCE_PARAM_PAYLOAD_VER;
```